# Interpret / Render the html string in Excel cell

Tags: .net-core, devexpress, spreadsheet, devextreme, richedit

I'm trying to interpret the string containing HTML tags and apply the stylings and add it in excel cell

using DevExpress spreadsheet to generate the excel file.
any help will be appreciated.

I tried using CellRangeObj.SetRichText( ) but is showing the string as it as